# VS code server failed to start

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote machine from my laptop in VS code and I keep getting "could not establish connection: the VS code server failed to start"
this is what im getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiyiY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmtSR.png)

```
[01:08:45.171] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at g.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:460179)
    at d (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:453522)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:455792)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:581100)
    at async c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:540958
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:544264)
    at async k (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:537923)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:541635)
    at async c:\Users\sanar\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.108.0\out\extension.js:2:807794
[01:08:45.231] ------
```

I looked at other people's posts who got the same error. I tried killing / uninstalling the VS code server on host and reconnecting and I did not work. my vsc is updated (version 1.86)

Comment: What OS (and for Linux, distribution and version) is running on the remote machine?

Comment: it's Linux - Ubuntu 18.04.6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using Ubuntu 18.04, which is [EOL except for paid security updates](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).  In VS Code 1.86, [Microsoft dropped support for glibc older than 2.28](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201129), and Ubuntu 18.04 uses glibc 2.27.  They did this because they chose to use the Node.js official binaries instead of the distro binaries, and Node.js made the same decision.

Note that it's generally never safe to upgrade glibc on a distro (since it will break lots of things), so you won't be able to use VS Code 1.86 on Ubuntu 18.04.  Most projects won't support distros that are only receiving non-public security updates (because they won't use insecure systems or pay extra money just to build a binary), so the fact that Ubuntu 18.04 is unsupported is not a surpirse.  This will also affect distros such as CentOS 7 which *are* receiving complimentary security updates, though, which is a bigger issue.

You can try pinning to VS Code 1.85 for a while, but since VS Code uses Electron, which is essentially the Chromium browser engine, almost every Electron release comes with a giant heap of security updates, so you're going to be in a bad situation security-wise if you do that long-term.  It does seem that [Microsoft plans an update for remote connections to fix this problem](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203375) at some point in the next week, so you may want to wait for that release to come out, which is expected to address the problem for 12 more months.

If the remote machine is one *you* maintain and control, now would be a great time to consider updating it to a new version.  You absolutely should be running a fully patched system if it's connected to the Internet so as not to be part of a botnet.